# Google play console API issues

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

[image]I am trying to upload a bundle (.aab) to put out a new update of an app.
I am able to bundle and sign properly, but when I try and upload the .aab I get this error

```
Your app currently targets API level 27 and must target at least API level 29 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 29. Learn More
You need to use a different version code for your APK or Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.
```

My gradle.build is targetting API 29 and the version code is 9. I'm not sure what's going on here.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.organization.myApplication
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 9
        versionName "9"
    }
...
}
```

One solution I have come across is to update app/build.gradle to target SDK 29 then sync project with gradle files. However, it tells me that this is not a gradle based project. From what I understand it is. I imported the project with gradle, there is a gradle wrapper and I have build.gradle and settings.gradle both in the top of the android folder. The build.gradle at the top level is a configuration buildscript, where as the build.gradle that targets SDK 29 is in the android/app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check one more time your sdk manager and targetSdkVersion. Error say that you have target api level 27, but it must be 29) and Bundle version code must be unique all time when you publish your app to google play)

Comment: Under the sdk manager, the only SDK platforms installed are API level 29 and 30. I just changed the targetSDKVersion to 30 from 29 in the gradle.build. And the project SDK under file>project structure is API 30

Comment: I also cant generate the build from within android studio. I have to use the console (which works fine), but android studio requires me to update Android Gradle Plugin to 3.2.0 or higher, but then points me to the build.gradle file where it is version 4.0.0...

Comment: I didn't know what it was Android Studio. I have same problem in unity, I fix it by delete older versions in sdk manager and set new setting in unity.

Comment: the oldest sdk version I have installed is 29

Comment: It so confused me) I never work in android studio. Can you show me your android adk? Maybe I can help with something.

Comment: What do you mean by android adk?

Comment: Sorry for mistackes, I mean sdk.

Comment: I added an image of what the sdk manager looks like in android studio

Comment: You can try to delete everythink where api 30 and install all where api is 29 and set 29 api in bulid

Comment: I can try that, but the bundle is targetting an API level I don't even have installed

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know any issures for this, I think you will fix it. You just have to look for solutions online.

Comment: no worries! thanks for trying to help though!

Answer (score 0):

I tagged it but should have mentioned this was a react-native project.

It seemed to work after redownloading and reimporting the project a bunch of times and getting lucky that android studio recognized Gradle. Under project structure, there was no choice for android gradle plugin or gradle version until it was recognized as a gradle project. Once it recognized the project as a gradle project then I could bundle the app from android studio rather than the command line. This seemed to work for google.

Also good to note that if you are making a react-native project, you'll need to open the android folder in android studio rather than the project's main folder. I didn't realize this at first and don't remember seeing and docs or anyone mentioning it before (probably missed it).